# Haskell type checking

Tags: haskell, typechecking

I am trying to do some self-learning with Haskell.

A function `loadData` reads some data off the file and based on an integer parameter does some processing on it to produce a Map. I need to create two such maps and apply a cosine similarity metric to it.I am trying to find the intersection of the two maps first. However, I run into a type error (`` Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Map.Map k0 a1' with actual type `IO (Map.Map [Char] Double)' ``) How can I feed the output of `loadData` to `Map.intersection`. Do I need a function applicator `$`?

```
loadData :: Int -> FilePath -> IO (Map.Map [Char] Double)

Map.intersection :: Ord k => Map.Map k a -> Map.Map k b -> Map.Map k a
```

Comment: Do you know how to handle IO yet?

Comment: How are you trying to feed the output of `loadData` to `Map.intersection`? Show us your code.

Comment: I just tried doing Map.intersection <$>(loadData 1 "firstFile") <$>(loadData 1 "secondFile")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import Control.Applicative

Map.intersection <$> loadData param filename1 <*> loadData param filename2
```

Note that the result of this has type `IO (Map.Map String Double)`.

Comment: I am probably not getting the mechanism of IO right. So if I once do a readFile in loadData that return an IO a , do I have to forever operate in the monadic context? Or is there a way to just sort of 'extract' a and use it?

Comment: You can 'extract' the value and use it using functions like `<$>`, `<*>`, `>>=` and the like. But you always end up with something in `IO`.

Comment: It is slightly more correct to say that you are forever operating in a monadic context, and the `<$>`, `<*>`, and `>>=` combinators are simply converting non-IO functions into ones that know how to deal with a bit of IO.

Comment: atlantis: remember that `main` is executed in the `IO` context, so from the main function, you can perform IO actions, and assign the result to a name with `<-`, and then give that result to a pure function. Behind the scenes, Haskell translates `do` notation, including `<-`, into `>>=`.

Answer (score 4):

As FUZxxl has mentioned in a comment to your question, I question how much you've looked into Haskell I/O.  This is one of the big initial hurdles to get over to make use of the language, and it seems like you'd want to start with simpler tasks.

But still, to answer your question more literally, here's two ways.  First, the elementary one, the one you need to understand first before the other ones make sense:

```
processData :: Int -> FilePath -> Int -> FilePath -> IO (Map.Map [Char] Double)
processData int1 path1 int2 path2 =
    do map1 <- loadData int1 path1
       map2 <- loadData int2 path2
       return (Map.intersection map1 map2)
```

There are more advanced answers that involve abstracting the pattern shown above into a function.  The more basic way to do this is to use the `liftM2` function from the `Control.Monad` module.  I'll give an example implementation of `liftM2` just to make it obvious how it's related to the code above:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
liftM2 f mx my = do x <- mx
                    y <- my
                    return (f x y)
```

With `liftM2`, we can rewrite `processData` this way:

```
processData :: Int -> FilePath -> Int -> FilePath -> IO (Map.Map [Char] Double)
processData int1 path1 int2 path2 =
    liftM2 Map.intersection (loadData int1 path1) (loadData int2 path2)
```

dave4420's answer is a bit more advanced; what it comes down to is that `Control.Applicative` has two operators (`<$>` and `<*>`) that in combination can do the same thing as `liftM2`, but for an arbitrary number of arguments for the function that liftM2 takes as its first argument.